# SQL Server 2008 Full Text Search results

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I''ve a little problem while using SQL Server Full Text Search.

Let me explain,

- I've a table with a BLOB inside (a PDF file).
- I've created the full text index in that table like it should be.
- I've the PDF iFilter from Adobe.

BUT, when I put some files in my table and execute a search like:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE FREETEXT(*, N'thank');
```

It only returns the columns from my table (well, that's what I asked, right?).

**But I wanted to return the sentence where the word 'thank' was found.**
Is there any way to do this?

I've been fighting with this issue for almost 2 days...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any evidence that the PDF IFilter is working from within SQL Server at all?
Just as a test put an MS Word 2003 doc in there and see if it gets indexed properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Well, I know it's working because I see a result (a row) from the query I wrote in my initial post. So I assume it is working.

My main problem here is returning the sentence where the word was found, much like any search engine does.

Comment: Your initial post said "It only returns the columns from my table", I assumed that to mean you had other non-blob columns that had that word in it and that's what it returned on.

Answering your question then, as far as I know this isn't possible as the IFilter doesn't provide any rendering capability.  That is SQL Server has no visibility of the text that matched the search condition.